# Editor could not be initialized error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Suddenly getting error "Editor could not be initialized" in eclipse, if trying to open any file. The project is building as expected.Only I am unable to open any file. I have attached the below image. Please let me know how I can resolve the issue. 
[image]

Comment: Eclipse has been told to use a class from a 3rd party plugin - 'com/mentor/....' but the class doesn't exist. Have you removed such a plugin recently?

Comment: Not sure. May be by mistake. It was working today morning and before sometime started this error.And if I close and open the eclipse again the last opened file which was having error will be opened in editor. But if I try for another file it will give same error.